# using websockets - multiple pages or single page

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a demo website using websockets that will be a simple blog.

Nodejs will serve the html templates using jade and the clientside scripts will get the blog data using websockets.

There will be separate pages to create/update blog, post a comment, edit a blog topic etc. By design, going to each page will establish a new websocket connection and disconnect the old one etc.

Is this the proper way of using websockets OR is it for single page applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets can be used in single page application (more frequently) and on multiple pages also, it's your decision. Since we're talking about a blog, I think you could try to make it a single page application, considering it's not that big.

By

> Nodejs will serve the html templates using jade and the clientside
>   scripts will get the blog data using websockets.

I guess you mean that the users will get in realtime new blog posts, comments etc, because getting the existing information on page display should happen by default (without ws)